# which event to use for readonly textfield when text is changed

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a readonly text field. I want that when the value is changed to this field , to set another text field also.

Which event should I use. tried with editingChanged , but it's not getting called.
pls help.

Comment: how you changes the read only text? and if it's changing then how can you call it as read only text?

Answer (score 0):

If the text field is readonly, then you must set the text programmatically, right? In that case, when you set the text, set the text of the other text field at the same time.

If I misunderstood your question, and the user edits the textfield, you can listen for changes this way:

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And handle the callback the following way:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Handle change
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Apple documentation

> textFieldShouldBeginEditing: Asks the delegate if editing should begin
>   in the specified text field.
>
> - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
>
> Parameters textField - The text field for which editing is about to
>   begin.
>
> Return Value YES if an editing session should be initiated; otherwise,
>   NO to disallow editing.
>
> Discussion When the user performs an action that would normally
>   initiate an editing session, the text field calls this method first to
>   see if editing should actually proceed. In most circumstances, you
>   would simply return YES from this method to allow editing to proceed.
>
> Implementation of this method by the delegate is optional. If it is
>   not present, editing proceeds as if this method had returned YES.

So use something like:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    BOOL editable;
    if (textField == myReadOnlyTextField) {
        editable = NO;
    } else if (textField == myEditableTextField) {
        editable = YES;
    } else {
        // editable = YES/NO/Other Logic
    }
    return editable;
}
```

Also in order for the delegate methods to get called your interface should conform to the UITextfieldProtocol: add this to your .h file `<UITextFieldDelegate>` so it looks like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement this delegate method if you are implementing in ios.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
shouldChangeCharactersInRange{}
```

If you are implementing in macos then use below delegate method:-

```
      -(void)controlTextDidChange
```